# Find a formula for the $n$th term in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series:
$$13,-\frac{13}{8},\frac{13}{27},-\frac{13}{64},\frac{13}{125},...$$
And I want to find it's $n$th term.

I tried to do $13 \times\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^{n-1}$, but this doesn't work. How would I start this problem?

Comment: hint $2^3 = 8,~~3^3=27,~~4^3=64,~~5^3=125$

Comment: how did the sequence come about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$13\times(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n^3}$